# leakage of define-key in let-bound keymap

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

I am trying to make a keymap to apply to a buffer region where the map is a composed keymap of several modes. Then, in that map, I want to define `C-c C-c` to run the command `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c`.

This is the code that I am using:

```lisp
(setq scimax-src-block-keymaps
      `(("emacs-lisp" . 
         ,(let ((map (make-composed-keymap `(,lispy-mode-map
                                             ,emacs-lisp-mode-map
                                             ,outline-minor-mode-map)
                                           org-mode-map)))
            (define-key map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c)
            map))))
```

This works fine, but I was surprised to learn that it "leaks". For example, if I open a Latex file, and turn on `outline-minor-mode`, then `C-c C-c` is bound to `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c` (note that before I run that code it is bound to the right command for latex-mode, but after I run that code it changes).

Am I doing this the wrong way? I would have thought this would make a copy of the maps and that I was modifying that copy, not that I was modifying the original maps here.

Comment: Good question. The result from `make-composed-keymap`, should be a new keymap. But it contains existing keymaps as components. 
The doc of `make-composed-keymap` speaks only about key lookup, not what happens when you define a key in the new map. Can you tell which of the component keymaps got altered? Maybe the doc of `make-composed-keymap` should be beefed up a bit, to make the behavior more clear about what happens when you bind a key in the composed map.

Comment: I'm guessing that @Stefan will provide a clear answer to this, if no one beats him to it.

Comment: It is only the binding of C-cC-c in the outline-minor-mode-map that gets modified.  It looks like if I make a copy-keymap around that composed map then the issue is avoided.  Although the docstring of that command says it is almost never needed, this scenario is a little more complicated than the one in the docstring, so maybe it is warranted here.

Comment: Doc string of what command? Or did you mean doc string of `make-composed-keymap`? And what did you mean by "it", in "it is almost never needed"? Does some doc string talk about copying the keymap? (I don't see that in the doc of `make-composed-keymap`.)

Comment: Sorry, in the docstring of `copy-keymap` it says "Note that this is almost never needed. "

Comment: It doesn't make a copy so that the new map inherits future changes in the component maps. I don't understand why `define-key` changes the component maps rather than the composed map.

Comment: From the comments here, at least, it seems like the doc is at least incomplete. Whether the behavior is also imperfect is a different question. Let's see what @Stefan says, to set us straight.

Answer (score 4):

Let us have a short look at the implementation of `make-composed-keymap` (in Emacs 26.3):

```el
(defun make-composed-keymap (maps &optional parent)
  "..."
  `(keymap
    ,@(if (keymapp maps) (list maps) maps)
    ,@parent))
```

The list `maps` is spliced in.

When called with two maps and one parent you get a list `(keymap (keymap el11 ... el1A) (keymap el21 ... el2B) . PARENT)`.

The doc `(info "(elisp)Format of Keymaps")` says:

> ‘(keymap ...)’
>        If an element of a keymap is itself a keymap, it counts as if this
>        inner keymap were inlined in the outer keymap.  This is used for
>        multiple-inheritance, such as in ‘make-composed-keymap’.

So the map is actually equivalent to `(keymap el11 .. el1A el21 ... el2B . PARENT)`.

If that is so `define-key` is free to insert the new definition into `(keymap el11 ... el1A)` instead of the top-level list.

And it does so as the following demo code shows.

```el
(let ((parent (make-sparse-keymap))
      (map1 (make-sparse-keymap))
      (map2 (make-sparse-keymap))
      composed)
  (define-key map1 [?1] 'sym1)
  (define-key map2 [?2] 'sym2)
  (setq composed (make-composed-keymap (list map1 map2) parent))
  (define-key composed [?3] 'sym3)
  (list :composed composed
    :map1 map1))

(:composed (keymap (keymap (51 . sym3) (49 . sym1)) (keymap (50 . sym2)) keymap)
 :map1 (keymap (51 . sym3) (49 . sym1)))
```

IMHO this is bad behavior of `define-key` and worth a bug-report.

What I actually would expect from `define-key` is to work like `(setcdr composed (cons '(?3 . sym3) (cdr composed)))` as shown in the following example:

```el
(let ((parent (make-sparse-keymap))
      (map1 (make-sparse-keymap))
      (map2 (make-sparse-keymap))
      composed)
  (define-key map1 [?1] 'sym1)
  (define-key map2 [?2] 'sym2)
  (setq composed (make-composed-keymap (list map1 map2) parent))
  (setcdr composed (cons '(?3 . sym3) (cdr composed)))
  (list :composed composed
    :map1 map1))

(:composed (keymap (51 . sym3) (keymap (49 . sym1)) (keymap (50 . sym2)) keymap)
 :map1 (keymap (49 . sym1)))
```

The resulting map is working as it should be:

```el
(lookup-key
  '(keymap (51 . sym3) (keymap (49 . sym1)) (keymap (50 . sym2)) keymap)
  [?3])

sym3
```

and it does not arbitrarily modify the inherited maps.

---

A **workaround** is to insert a sacrificial sparse keymap as first element into the `MAP` argument of `make-composed-keymap`:

```el
(setq scimax-src-block-keymaps
      `(("emacs-lisp" . 
         ,(let ((map (make-composed-keymap (list
                                             (let ((map1 (make-sparse-keymap)))
                                               (define-key map1 (kbd "C-c") (make-sparse-keymap))
                                               map)
                                             lispy-mode-map
                                             emacs-lisp-mode-map
                                             outline-minor-mode-map)
                                           org-mode-map)))
            (define-key map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c)
            map))))
```

Note that the sacrificial map should bind <kbd>C-c</kbd> as prefix such that <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> is bound later there and not in `outline-minor-mode-map`.

Confer to the doc string for `define-key` in that regard:

> If KEYMAP is a sparse keymap with a binding for KEY, the existing
>   binding is altered.  If there is no binding for KEY, the new pair
>   binding KEY to DEF is added at the front of KEYMAP.

Our problem imposed by this doc is that the prefix key <kbd>C-c</kbd> is already bound in `outline-minor-mode-map` to a keymap. So the binding there is modified if we do not bind <kbd>C-c</kbd> again in our sacrificial map.

Alternatively, you can also immediately bind <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> in the sacrificial keymap.